# separating class for measures on a product space

Tags: functional-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $E$ be a normed $\mathbb R$-vector space and $$\varphi_{x'y'}(x,y):=\langle x,x'\rangle\langle y,y'\rangle\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E$$ for $x',y'\in E'$. Assume $E\times E$ is equipped with the norm $$\left\|(x,y)\right\|_{E^2}:=\max(\|x\|_E,\|y\|_E)\;\;\;\text{for }x,y\in E.$$ We should have $\varphi_{x'y'}\in (E\times E)'$ for all $x',y'\in E'$, but do we actually have $$(E\times E)'=\{\varphi_{x'y'}:x',y'\in E'\}?\tag1$$

*Remark*: If $(1)$ does not hold, the result I'm actually looking for is the following: We know that $\{e^{{\rm i}x'}:x'\in E'\}$ is separating for the class of Radon measures on $\mathcal B(E)$. Now I wonder whether $\{e^{{\rm i}\varphi_{x'y'}}:x',y'\in E'\}$ is searapting for the class of Radon measures on $\mathcal B(E\times E)$.